# Microsoft Azure SSO via SAML - NameID Format

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to integrate my application with Microsoft Azure SSO using SAML. Unlike the Google SSO SAML, their XML file does not contain the Name ID Format. Therefore I assume that it is "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress".

The SSO login works, but somehow the attributes return from Microsoft Azure looks weird. What I expect is the user information (e.g., first name, last name and other attributes I set in the control panel), instead, it returns something like:

```
[samlUserdata] => Array
        (
            [http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123456-a43f-4dfd-8888-f5fa5e547790
                )

            [http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123456-e20c-46f1-8888-204cc360d7d8
                )

            [http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://sts.windows.net/123456-a43f-4dfd-8888-f5fa5e547790/
                )

            [http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences] => Array
                (
                    [0] => urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
                )

        )
```

What am I missing?

P.S. I am using One Login PHP library. It works with Google.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore I assume that it is "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress".

I suppose a more appropriate format should be `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified`, specially if you are to leave it *unspecified*.

> What am I missing?

It seems as though your SAML2 IdP, Microsoft Azure SSO, is not correctly set up to release claims/attributes to you. I don't think this has anything to do with nameid formats; it's about the IdP configuration and its attribute release policy. You can cross check this by looking at the raw SAML2 XML response that should be passed back to your SP. If you do not find any claims/attributes in there, then the IdP is not releasing anything to you and that's something to take up with them.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure AD data is correct.

In Azure AD, a lot of attributes are GUID's and that is what you are seeing.

You will note that "authnmethodsreferences" is in plain text.

If you pass given name, surname etc. they will also be in plain text.

Comment: Can you point me how to convert the data into plain text, so that I can read the user's information (e.g., first name, email)? Thanks.

Comment: How is AAD passing user name etc.? Is it a GUID?

Comment: This is an Enterprise Application? What format are the claims in if you click the "Test this application" tab?